# Где кончается контроллер и начинается сервис?

Tags: php, laravel, service, controller

Никак не могу понять, где кончается работа контроллера и начинается сервис (и сервис ли) ?

Сразу распишу варианты сложных для меня сценариев:

1) Нужно вывести статьи в зависимости от роли пользователя. Админу все, пользователю только свои. И тут у меня ступор: разве в контроллере может быть логика по выбору метода в зависимости от Роли? Разве сервис должен работать с системой авторизации конкретного приложения?

2) Сервис выдает какие либо данные, метод один. Этот метод вызывается в разных частях приложения и данные по разному форматируются перед выводом на экран. Где должно происходить форматирование? В контроллере, а разве это не какая-никакая логика? Или сервис? Но разве сервису не должно быть по барабану на форматирование, его задача отдать обработанные данные.

3.1) Сервис поддерживает шаблон проектирование обсервер. Значит мы должны перед его использованием загрузить его наблюдателями, причем явно уровнем выше. Но тогда это уже контроллер, и получается логика в контроллере.

3.2) По сути любой сервис может быть подвергнут какому нибудь шаблону проектирования: декоратор, стратегия и т.д. И всегда это будет уровень выше сервиса - контроллер. Разве правильно делать это в контроллере?

Comment: Контроллер по сути есть первая станция обработки запроса после прокладок, так что остальная архитектура может быть выделена в своё ядро и работать там. Аналоги этого - events, поставщики услуг и остальные части вне основного ядра обработки запроса. Для вас, вероятно, будет важнее определить сначала основы вашей архитектуры, а уже после этого определить как её использовать из контроллера.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый комментарий, только вот примерную "теорию" я читал не раз, а вот когда встретился с практикой (реальные примеры я привел) - встал в ступор, куда направить данный функционал. Хотел послушать мнения, как бы поступили люди конкретно в данных простых примерах.

Comment: Чтобы узнать "конкретику", нужно код приводит, а так ответы и комментарии останутся "теорией".

Comment: @Pavel, значит пока вам не стоит слишком далеко залезать с планированием по теории. Пишите код как есть, в процессе прийдете к рефакторингу и поймёте как лучше организовать его используя архитектурные шаблоны и практики. Не всё сразу. Если нет понимания где и что можно использовать, значит надо начинать с малого к большему, а не наоборот.